# How to modify the entries titles in the projects section in CMS

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

I want to modify the title names besides the text boxes in the wp-admin project page. Kindly check the sceenshot here:

https://snag.gy/75oUTb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a custom post type which is called as Projects. You can modify titles of fields from ACF plugin by editing related ACF fields.

Comment: the post type called : bunch_projects